# how to read key/value from a column which values are JSON type in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to read  the column which type is json, values in column  look like this

```
                 column1
---------------------------------------------
 "[{'name': 'Kate', 'position': 'painter'}]"
```

Im using this query, but all I get is null, what can I do to get the values for each keys?

```
SELECT
   column1 ->> 'name' AS name
FROM
   table1;
```

Comment: If that is really how the value is stored, you only have a **single** value which is neither an array nor a list of key/value pairs. It's essentially the same as storing something like `"(foo)"`. And that means you can't really apply any JSON function on it unless you fix that data. Something got messed up when you stored that value in the database. A correct JSON value with an array and key/value pairs would need to look like this: `'[{"name": "Kate", "position": "painter"}]'` (note the reversed use of single and double quotes)

Comment: oh I understand your answer! if my data is wrong with reversed  quotes, why is that database says its json still?

Comment: As I said: it treats it as a single (scalar) value, not as a structured value. Similar to `'"42"'` or `'"(foobar)"'`

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) function:

```
SELECT json_array_elements(t) -> 'name'
FROM table1;
```

Comment: hi how can I make this code work for all rows in a table? this is only for one entry, thank u!

Comment: No, this is for all rows, you just do it like this `SELECT json_array_elements(t) -> 'name'  FROM table1;`

Comment: hi, I tried that one also and it throws this error [22023] ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar, I couldnt find the solution :(

Comment: How did you create your table? I made it this way `CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE json_values (col json);` and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Then you use jsonb_pretty that Returns from_json as indented JSON text.

```
select jsonb_pretty('[{"name": "Kate", "position": "painter"}]');
```

Output display you:

```
         jsonb_pretty
-------------------------------
 [                            +
     {                        +
         "name": "Kate",      +
         "position": "painter"+
     }                        +
 ]
```

so in your case you use

```
SELECT  jsonb_pretty(column1) AS name FROM table1;
```